# Reuse same instance of a component twice in a html Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

```html
           
            <!-- Top Pagination -->
             <app-pagination-list [totalCount]='totalRecords' [limitPerPage]='16' (pageSelected)="pageSelected($event)"></app-pagination-list>
            
            <!-- Patient List -->
            <ul class="patients-list">
        
                    <li class="patients-list-item deactivated"  *ngFor="let patient of patients" [ngClass]="{'deactivated': patient.is_activated == 0}">
                       
        
                        <div class="patient-info-container">
                            <h3 class="patient-name mobile">
                                {{ patient.firstname }} {{ patient.lastname }}
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </li>                    
                </ul>
            <!-- Patient List End -->
            <!-- Bottom Pagination -->
            <app-pagination-list [totalCount]='totalRecords' [limitPerPage]='16' (pageSelected)="pageSelected($event)"></app-pagination-list>
```

I have created a pagination component and I am using it on top and bottom of the page . The top and bottom paginator acts as two different components. When I change top pagination it should sync with the bottom one but that's not happening. Is there any way I can use the same instance of pagination component twice so both are synchronized?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @PierreDuc I have updated the description with html code . Please refer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are tracking the current page in the pagination component.  I assume this is what is not synced between the two. You should instead track it in the parent component and pass it to pagination as an input. Either that or make a service to sync the current page between the two pagination components.

Comment: Thanks a lot . You were right . I should track the selected page from parent component and sent it to pagination component as input .

Answer (score 0):

> i have an other solution : using ngx-agination

```
 *ngFor="let patient of patients | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: p }"
```

> and you put this code below into your template

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"    style="float:right; ></pagination-controls>
```

> and for sure you have to import ngxPagination module and add it to the imports:

```
import { NgxPaginationModule } from "ngx-pagination";
```